# INVALID_CLIENT when trying to use Spotipy to authorize an api call

Tags: python, api, authorization, spotipy

I'm attempting to call the Spotify API and have set up an app/got my client ID and Secret. Here's an example of my code (with specifics blocked out):

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

cid ="xx" 
secret = "xx"
username = "xx"

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

scope = 'user-library-read playlist-read-private'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,scope,client_id='http://localhost:8888/callback/',client_secret='http://localhost:8888/callback/',redirect_uri='http://localhost:8888/callback/')

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
cache_token = token.get_access_token()

sp = spotipy.Spotify(cache_token)
currentfaves = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=20, offset=0, time_range='medium_term')

print(currentfaves)
```

I've made sure my URL is exactly the same as what's registered in my Spotify app development page, and I've added the client ID, redirect URIs and client Secret keys to my environment variables.

So far a separate tab opens up (https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fcallback%2F&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fcallback%2F&scope=playlist-read-private+user-library-read) but I'm only getting 'INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid client' on that page. What can I do/change to make this work?

Comment: You put your Redirect URI for the Client ID and Client secret. Adjust those values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,scope,client_id='http://localhost:8888/callback/',client_secret='http://localhost:8888/callback/',redirect_uri='http://localhost:8888/callback/')
```

Is there a typo in here, since you copied the redirect uri also as the client id and secret?

Comment: This was it! Thank you!